# Server delay on system command in C

Tags: c, sockets, system

I have two programs, one acting as a server and one acting as a client. They are supposed to act like you are connecting to remote system using ssh. The client sends a command and the server executes the command and prints the output to the server. Although my code does exactly that, there is a delay on the output after the first command. For example if the client sents `date`, the server will return the date. If the client sends `date` again it will print `message was received` but not the output. On the third input from client, the second date will be executed and print on the client `Here is the message:date` and so on. Any ideas would be really apreciated.

Server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define MAX_PINS 1
void error(const char *msg){
     perror(msg);
     exit(1);
}

void exec_comm(int sock,int nerror,char buff[]){
     dup2(sock,1);
     dup2(nerror,2);
     if(system(buff)==-1){
          printf("command not found\n");
     }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, pid;
  socklen_t clilen;
  char buffer[256];
  char* comm[20],*cbuff;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
  int n,i,done=0,correct=0;
  char str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
  char* args,*pins[MAX_PINS]={"1234"},pin[10];
  FILE* fd;
  int nerror;
     if (argc < 2){
       fprintf(stderr, "No port provided\n");
       exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0)
     error("ERROR opening socket");
     memset((char *) &serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
     error("ERROR on binding");

          listen(sockfd, 5);
          clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
          newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
          if (newsockfd < 0)
          error("ERROR on accept");
          if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, &cli_addr.sin_addr, str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN) == NULL) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Could not convert byte to address\n");
          exit(1);
          }
          fprintf(stdout, "The client address is :%s\n", str);
while(1){
               bzero(buffer, 256);
               n = read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);
               sscanf(buffer,"%s\n",buffer);
               printf("The message that was read was:\t%s\n",buffer);
               if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
               fprintf(fd,"%s\n",buffer);
               if(strcmp(buffer,"exit\n")==0||strcmp(buffer,"exit")==0){
                    printf("Exiting...\n");
                    done=1;
                    break;
               }
               exec_comm(newsockfd,nerror,buffer);
               printf("Here is the message: %s\n", buffer);
               n = write(newsockfd, "message received", 17);
               if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
          }

     fclose(fd);
     close(newsockfd);
     close(sockfd);
     return 0;
}
```

Client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
void error(const char *msg){
     perror(msg);
     exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
     int sockfd, portno, n;
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
     struct hostent *server;
     char buffer[256];
     if (argc < 3){
          fprintf(stderr, "usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
          exit(0);
     }
     portno = atoi(argv[2]);
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0)
     error("ERROR opening socket");
     server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
     if (server == NULL){
          fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, no such host\n");
          exit(0);
     }
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,
     (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_length);
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
     error("ERROR connecting");
     n = write(sockfd, stdin, sizeof(int));
     if (n < 0)
     error("ERROR writing to socket");
     do{
          printf("Please enter the message: ");

          bzero(buffer, 256);
          fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);
          if(strcmp(buffer,"exit\n")==0||strcmp(buffer,"exit")==0){
               printf("Exiting...\n");
               n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
               if (n < 0)
               error("ERROR writing to socket");
               close(sockfd);
               break;
          }
          n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
          if (n < 0)
          error("ERROR writing to socket");
          bzero(buffer, 256);
          n = read(sockfd, buffer, 255);
          if (n < 0)
          error("ERROR reading from socket");
          printf("%s\n", buffer);
     }while(1);

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is the server ignoring the data loaded by the first read - the one before the loop?

Comment: Oops, forgot to delete that. I now deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
```

That's your problem right here. Calls to `write` do not result in individual distinguishable messages, one message per call. They result in a single homogenous stream (that's the "stream" in `SOCK_STREAM`) of bytes with no delimiters.

You have newlines that separate commands, which is nice and all, but `read` has no idea about newlines. It will just wait until the buffer is full, or enough time has passed, or whatever. You have **no** control over it.

You basically have 2 ways to fix this.

1. Read character by character (pass the length of 1) and stop as soon as you see a newline. Accumulate the characters in a buffer, then execute it.
2. Send the length of each message before the message itself, in a fixed-length record, so that the server can safely read the length and then use it to read the message itself.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a ton of duplicates, but I don't have much time to find the right one, it was easier to just write a new answer. If you find a better answer, feel free to link.

Comment: I have solved this problem by adding ```sscanf(buffer,"%s\n",buffer);``` to my server when the soket is read but unfortunately that does not solve my problem.

Comment: @Azzarian You have solved your problem but that doesn't solve your problem. Understood. Maybe that wasn't your problem in the first place?

Comment: I mean that I solved the problem that YOU are implying with the newline character but the problem I am referring to on THIS thread, still persists.

Comment: No, sorry. It doesn't look like you understood what I'm saying. I'm not saying that you have a newline problem. I'm not saying that removing newlines will solve your problem. (You probably should remove them anyway, but that's a completely different problem.) Please try reading what is actually written.

Comment: I am sorry but would you mind explaining it to me with an example?